# Using multiple dynamic cells with different layouts

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

I was using this solutions for my tableview, I have cells containing only text and cells with also an image, so I want to use a solution with storyboards and dynamic cells to layout the different cells and with this code change the CellIdentifier

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
NSDictionary *object = [self.listOfStuff objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if ([[object objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"text"]){
    CellIdentifier = @"OnlyTextCell";
}else if ([[object objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"image"]){
    CellIdentifier = @"ImageTextCell";
}
```

Do I've to use different UITableViewCells like:
- OnlyTextCell
- ImageTextCell

```
OnlyTextCell *cell = (OnlyTextCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
ImageTextCell *cell = (ImageTextCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

And then `return cell`

Something is missing here, because I also know that *cell twice is not working...

So I'm getting this kind of code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

    TTTTimeIntervalFormatter *timeIntervalFormatter = [[TTTTimeIntervalFormatter alloc] init];
    NSString *timestamp = [timeIntervalFormatter stringForTimeInterval:[[object objectForKey:@"datum"] timeIntervalSinceNow]];


    if ([[object objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"text"]){
        ChatCell *cell = (ChatCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChatCell"];
        // Send the text over to the cell.
        NSLog(@"ChatCell");

        cell.naamGebruiker.text = [[object objectForKey:@"fromUser"] objectForKey:@"accountName"];
        cell.timeLabel.text = timestamp;

        cell.gebruikerImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        PFFile *thumbnail = [[object objectForKey:@"fromUser"] objectForKey:@"facebookImage"];
        cell.gebruikerImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no-image"];
        cell.gebruikerImage.file = thumbnail;

        [cell.gebruikerImage loadInBackground];

        cell.gebruikerImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.gebruikerImage.frame.size.height /2;
        cell.gebruikerImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        cell.gebruikerImage.layer.borderWidth = 0;

        cell.chatBerichtTekst.text = [object objectForKey:@"tekst"];
        cell.chatBerichtTekst.numberOfLines = 0;
        [cell.chatBerichtTekst setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        [cell sizeToFit];

        return cell;

    } else if ([[object objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"image"]){
        ChatImageCell *cell = (ChatImageCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChatImageCell"];
        // Send the image over the cell.
        NSLog(@"ChatImageCell");

        cell.naamGebruiker.text = [[object objectForKey:@"fromUser"] objectForKey:@"accountName"];
        cell.timeLabel.text = timestamp;

        cell.gebruikerImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        PFFile *thumbnail = [[object objectForKey:@"fromUser"] objectForKey:@"facebookImage"];
        cell.gebruikerImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no-image"];
        cell.gebruikerImage.file = thumbnail;

        [cell.gebruikerImage loadInBackground];

        cell.gebruikerImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.gebruikerImage.frame.size.height /2;
        cell.gebruikerImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        cell.gebruikerImage.layer.borderWidth = 0;

        cell.chatBerichtTekst.text = [object objectForKey:@"tekst"];
        cell.chatBerichtTekst.numberOfLines = 0;
        [cell.chatBerichtTekst setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        [cell sizeToFit];

        return cell;
    }

    return nil;


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set the cell identifier in each dynamic cell of your Storyboard to the correct OnlyTextCell and ImageTextCell.  Then in your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: you should have something like this…

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary *object = [self.listOfStuff objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([[object objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"text"]){
        OnlyTextCell *cell = (OnlyTextCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OnlyTextCell"];
        // Send the text over to the cell.
        return cell;
    }else if ([[object objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"image"]){
        ImageTextCell *cell = (ImageTextCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ImageTextCell"];
        // Send the image over the cell.
        return cell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Thnx, I edit the complete code above in my question. Error is in the data I get, i think...